# MS Access Run Time Error 2465 Can't find the field 'employeeNum' referred to in your expression

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

Just finished tweaking a query, then started testing the change and then this issue popped up.
In a Module called GLOBALS I declare a number of public variables.  One of which is this:
Public employeeNum As Long '  PO entering/modifying data

In form frmSearch I assign this variable.  For some reason I am getting a run time that I catch in my Form_Load() procedure.
[image: Run Time Error I capture]

Here is a pic of when I stop at the breakpoint and hoover over the global variable employeeNum.

[image: Error message during breakpoint]

Any thoughts on this strange error?
Attempts to fix include the following:

1. Ran Compact and Repair Database a couple of times and no luck.
2. Ran /decompile to clean things up. No luck.
3. Compiled Database to validate no issues and no errors detected.
4. Changed Public to Global when declaring employeeNum. No luck.
5. Tried to debug.print employeeNum early in the procedure but I still would get the runtime error on the debug.print line.

Thanks

Comment: Run the SQL command directly via database tools and see what's the result.

Comment: I ran the SQL via DB tools and that runs without error. Thanks

Comment: Seems the error is complaining about a missing `employeeNum` *field*, not a variable.  Unclear how the variable contributes to the error.  Perhaps it would make sense if you show us the full `SELECT` statement (as text, please, not as an image).

Comment: Here is the full select. But that is not the issue. The problem is the employeeNum variable not the rs!employeeNum (this has a valid variable)

Comment: Dim sql As String: sql = "SELECT employeeNum FROM staff WHERE userid = '" & getUserName() & "';"

Comment: I am with HansUp. The error 2465 refers to *Microsoft Access cannot find the field...* refers to the `employeeNum` column in SQL (not VBA variable). Please run that `SELECT` query in Query Design, does an *Enter Parameter* pop-up occur. If so, there is no such column in the `staff` table.

Comment: @HansUp and Parfait ok, you gave me the clues to figure this out. Using the object browser I found an object called employeeNum on the form. Same name as my global var employeeNum. I renamed the global var to employeeNumber and everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by two variables being named the same.  A global variable and a local variable (employeeNum).  The various replies gave me the clue I needed and I used the Object Browser to validate the problem.  When I tried to find the object, the Object Browser stated it was hidden which is annoying but I’ll go through all the embedded code, etc. and figure out where it is just so I know.

I renamed the global variable employeeNum to employeeNumber throughout the application and everything works fine.